# HTACCESS Redirect ID Value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574913/mod-rewrite-help)

Looking to redirect `/careers/4/job-title/` to `/careers.php?id=4`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: Pierre - I've tried a number of different solutions and I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @ryanka: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess udner DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^careers/([0-9]+)/ careers.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I ended up using:

RewriteRule ^careers/(\d+)/(.*)$ /careers.php?id=$1

Which is essentially the same thing with the addition of the job title. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes it is same however since you're not really using matched text after `\d+` therefore you might as well use: `RewriteRule ^careers/(\d+)/ careers.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`