# htaccess redirect value and discard key

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do an Apache `.htaccess` redirect as follows:

```
https://domain1.com/app/index.php?ref=1234
```

to

```
https://domain2.com/ref/1234
```

How is it possible to write this rule? It seems that I want to discard the `ref=` parameter and then dynamically use the value (1234 in this example).

There are thousands of URL's so the value (1234) needs to be obtained dynamically.

I have read [HTACCESS Redirect ID Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896058/htaccess-redirect-id-value) and https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/ but can't seem to get this working.

I've tried this in the `.htaccess` for domain1.com:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?ref=/([0-9]+)/ https://domain2.com/ref/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) *Pattern* will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and **before the query string**. If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables.

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ref=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php https://domain2.com/ref/%1 [R,L,NC,QSD]
```